# Передача массива из PHP в JavaScript(Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Здравствуйте!
Мне нужно чтобы когда пользователь вводил логин он сразу проверялся через php и mysql и если такой есть то false если нет то true. Я скрипт почти написал но проблема в том что я не знаю как сделать так чтобы в js уже передавался массив из значений.

Вот скрипт:

```
$("#name").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (name == data.login) $("#go").text("Такой логин уже существует, попробуйте ввести другой!");
                else $("#go").text("Этот логин свободный!");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("#go").text("");
    }
});
```

Скрипт файла php:

```
mysql\_connect("localhost", "admin", "12345");  
mysql\_select\_db("test_db");

$result = mysql\_query("SELECT * FROM test");  
$myrow = mysql\_fetch\_array($result);  
echo json\_encode($myrow);
```

Нужно, чтобы в ajax запросе сразу проверялось по массиву есть ли такой логин. Обычными способами через while у меня что-то не получилось (не так видно делал =))
За скрипт строго не судите, я с js работаю не долго =) Помогите, пожалуйста!
З.Ы. Если можно расскажите все в подробностях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вы вообще так сделали? Вы передаёте клиенту список ВСЕХ пользователей? А что вы будете делать, когда у вас будет 50М пользователей (гипотетически)? А представляете какой огромный трафик будет?

Вам не нужен никакой массив. Вам надо передавать на сервер имя пользователя, а на сервере его проверять и возвращать уже простой ответи наподобие успехнеудача.

Понятное дело, что while на клиенте не будет успешным, если на сервере не выдали массив. Хотя это в целом и неправильный подход, тем не менее, вы можете получить из базы ВСЕ строки и заэнкодить их.

Что-то в таком духе

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: А что в этом случае нужно будет писать в js коде?

Comment: проверять true или false в ответе сервера и отдавать результат

Answer (score 5):

на стороне сервера отдавай как:

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'data' => $data)); // лично мне такой формат привычнее
/*
 *либо просто 
 */
echo json_encode($data);

exit; // - обязательно
```

На стороне клиента:

```
success: function (data) {
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON( data );

   // Если на стороне серевера $data есть ничто инной как массив, то
   for(i in result)
     if (name == result[i].login)
       ...

   //Если просто значение

   if (name == result.login)
      ...

}
```

на вскидку как-то так